# Is there a NODE_ENV equivalent in Python

Tags: python, node.js, virtualenv, setuptools, setup.py

Is there a NODE_ENV equivalent in Python?

I want to dynamically load JSON configurations to the python application based on the executing environment. In nodeJs, I do this by using the process.env.NODE_ENV.

For example,

I start the app like this,

```
NODE_ENV=production node server.js
```

And use the variable in the application like this,

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
    // Load the production config file here (eg: database.json)
} else {
    // Load the development config file here (located in a different directory)
}
```

How can I achieve the same in Python? Or can I make use of python virtualenv or python setuptools to have a workaround?

Comment: you can set up environment variables in python. https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starters, you could do something like this.

```
import os
env = os.environ.get("PYTHON_ENV")
if(env =="production"):
   //
else :
```

The script can be run with `PYTHON_ENV="production" python myscript.py`. Or you could use some library like dotenv(https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv).

Answer (score 1):

*you can try environs library in python*
 `pip install environs`